# Партицирование таблицы по дате

Tags: mysql, partition, multi-index

Есть таблица с 40+ млн записей, и для быстродействия возникла необходимость ее партицировать по дате. Партицирование требует PRIMARY ключ на поле, по которому будем разбивать таблицу, поэтому PRIMARY получился по полям (`id`, `date`), потому что в таблицу очень часто вставляются записи, и поле `date` может дублироваться. В итоге получилась таблица вида

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `orders` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `date`);
ALTER TABLE `orders` MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Далее создаем партиции

```
ALTER TABLE `orders`  
PARTITION BY RANGE (`date`) PARTITIONS 6 ( 
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1420059600) ENGINE = InnoDB COMMENT = '< 01.01.2015',  
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1483218000) ENGINE = InnoDB COMMENT = '< 01.01.2017',  
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (1496264400) ENGINE = InnoDB COMMENT = '< 01.06.2017',  
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (1514764800) ENGINE = InnoDB COMMENT = '< 01.01.2018',  
PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (1527811200) ENGINE = InnoDB COMMENT = '< 01.06.2018',  
PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB COMMENT = 'Current part')
```

Получается, что у нас составной PRIMARY. И если выполнить запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `id`=1 AND `date` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

то задействуется составной PRIMARY и выборка будет максимально быстрой. А если сделать

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `id`=1;
```

или

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `date` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

то произойдет фулл скан таблицы (согласно [этой статье](https://habr.com/post/70640/))
Правильно ли будет создать обычные индексы на поля `id` и `date`, чтобы делать выборку только по ним

```
ALTER TABLE `orders`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `date`),
  ADD KEY `id` (`id`),
  ADD KEY `date` (`date`);
```

Или составной PRIMARY работает как-то иначе, чем обычный составной ключ?

Comment: *для быстродействия возникла необходимость ее партицировать по дате* Обоснуйте. *Партицирование требует PRIMARY ключ на поле, по которому будем разбивать таблицу* Кто Вам сказал этот бред? *А если сделать ... то произойдет фулл скан таблицы (согласно этой статье)* Вы, похоже, вообще не поняли, о чём статья. Запрос с отбором по `id` прекрасно МОЖЕТ использовать этот индекс (правда, неизвестно, будет ли, но это определяется совсем иными факторами).

Comment: Да совсем не бред. Ошибка `ERROR 1503 (HY000): A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function`

Comment: [Документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-overview.html) считает следующее: *All columns used in the table's partitioning expression must be part of every unique key that the table may have, including any primary key.* Это совсем не то же самое, что Вы говорите. Хотя да - общих слов много.